# What is this error in winston?

Tags: node.js, winston

```
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: write after end
at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:236:12)
at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:287:5)
at exports.File.File._write (/home/baopham/Documents/Projects/temp/api/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js:202:18)
at /home/baopham/Documents/Projects/temp/api/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js:438:12
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

I log by winston.

```
winston.loggers.add('logger',{});
    winston.loggers.get('query').configure({
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.File({ dirname: 
            path.join(__dirname, '/../../../logs'), filename: 'query.log', timestamp: false })
        ]
    });
winston.loggers.get('query').info('CREATE ITEM');
```

node v8.11.3

npm v5.6.0

What is this error ?
I do not know if it is related to the npm

Comment: Can you use npm 6.1.0  or above ? I think this is fixed.

Comment: I tried it and it was not

Comment: if you are facing this issue in latest version 6.1.0 please add her https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19989 . There are lot of workaround for the same . check this out . This will help them also , why the error coming every time in different builds .

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix:

** Upgrade node to 8.10.x (This actually downgrades your npm to 5.6.0)

** Then update npm using **$ npm install npm -g** (This will update npm to 5.7.1)

Now npm install will work smoothly.

Reference: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19989